# Overnight shift

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have output data from 3 machines for manufacturing.  The output looks like this:

```
ID      MachineId   ProgramNo               StartTime       StopTime        Cycle   Idle
327628  3           W5_2020_OPP2.MPF        12/15/15 23:29  12/15/15 23:29  0:00:00 0:00:04
327629  3           W5_2020_OPP2.MPF        12/15/15 23:30  12/15/15 23:39  0:09:25 0:01:02
327632  1           880995_610_DN_BOTH.MPF  12/15/15 23:40  12/16/15 0:37   0:56:40 0:10:31
327633  3           W5_2020_OPP2.MPF        12/15/15 23:40  12/15/15 23:40  0:00:08 0:37:35
327634  2           3620_06_OPP1.MPF        12/15/15 23:58  12/16/15 0:07   0:09:08 0:04:38
327635  2           3620_06_OPP1.MPF        12/16/15 0:11   12/16/15 0:14   0:02:32 0:03:05
327636  2           3620_06_OPP1.MPF        12/16/15 0:17   12/16/15 0:34   0:17:08 0:00:41
327637  3           W5_2020_OPP2.MPF        12/16/15 0:18   12/16/15 0:18   0:00:00 0:00:00
327638  3           W5_2020_OPP2.MPF        12/16/15 0:18   12/16/15 0:33   0:15:41 0:02:42
327639  2           3620_06_OPP1.MPF        12/16/15 0:35   12/16/15 0:52   0:16:47 0:09:26
327640  3           W5_2020_OPP2.MPF        12/16/15 0:36   12/16/15 0:36   0:00:00 0:00:06
327641  3           W5_2020_OPP2.MPF        12/16/15 0:36   12/16/15 0:52   0:15:40 0:27:57
327645  1           880995_610_DN_BOTH.MPF  12/16/15 0:47   12/16/15 1:44   0:56:42 0:02:03
```

We have 2 shifts that run these machines, 6 am - 4 pm and 4:30 pm - 2:30 am.  I need to total the cycle time for each shift grouped on the program number and machineid.  I can get shift 1 to total easily, is the overnight shift I'm having trouble with.  I've thought about splitting the second shift up into two groups, before midnight and after midnight, but there are some cases where the program will start just before midnight and end just after.  Or would it be easier to just sum the difference between start and stop times without even using the column cycle?  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I haven't tried to do the total yet, primarily have focused on just finding the records first. I also wasn't too concerned with stopping directly at 2 am, just so long as it was before 6 am of the 1st shift.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Cycle 
WHERE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartTime, 108) >= '16:30:00'
    AND 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DD, 1, StartTime), 108) < '06:00:00'
```

Comment: What language are you using for this?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: T-SQL in SQL R2 2008.  I haven't tried to do the total yet, primarily have focused on just finding the records first.  I also wasn't too concerned with stopping directly at 2 am, just so long as it was before 6 am of the 1st shift.  SELECT * FROM Cycle WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartTime, 108) >= '16:30:00' 
and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DD, 1, StartTime), 108) < '06:00:00'

Comment: That information needs to be in the original question...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your needs, and assuming TSQL, just back the dates up by 3 hours so you don't have to deal with the crossover.  Then you can use a BETWEEN for 3am-1pm and 1:30pm-11:30pm to get your groups.

```
SELECT ProgramNo, MachineId, DATEADD(HOUR, -3, StartTime) AS StartTime, DATEADD(HOUR, -3, StopTime) AS StopTime, Cycle, Idle
FROM {tableName}
```

EDIT:  Given the query recently added to comments above by OP, my quick and dirty solution would be something like this:

```
SELECT ProgramNo, MachineId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartTime, 108) BETWEEN '3:00:00' AND '13:00:00' THEN Cycle ELSE 00:00:00 END) AS Shift1Cycle,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartTime, 108) BETWEEN '13:30:00' AND '23:30:00' THEN Cycle ELSE 00:00:00 END) AS Shift2Cycle,
FROM
(
    SELECT ProgramNo, MachineId, DATEADD(HOUR, -3, StartTime) AS StartTime, DATEADD(HOUR, -3, StopTime) AS StopTime, Cycle, Idle
    FROM Cycle
) a
GROUP BY ProgramNo, MachineId
```

Obviously there are going to be some edge cases, as mentioned in the comments, but this take care of the simple use case given.  The SUM should be the resulting hours, minutes, and seconds of Cycle with a date of 01/01/1900.

Comment: what happens if they start a shift at 1AM for emergency reason ? :)